# What is wrong with my while loop in this java program?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

When I run the program it runs the **else** part and executes but on the **if** part it just keeps looping and doesn't stop until I have to forcibly stop it. I'm trying to give it parameters on the *choice* from 1 to 4 and parameters to *meters* that doesn't go under 1. is there an alternative to having the parameters?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Project4

{
    public static void showKilometers(double meters) //this is a parameterized function

    {
        double kilometers = meters * 0.001;
        System.out.println(meters +" meters is " + kilometers + " kilometers.");
    }

    public static void showInches(double meters)
    {
        double inches = meters * 39.37;
        System.out.println(meters +" meters is " + inches + " inches.");
    }

    public static void showFeet(double meters)
    {
        double feet = meters * 3.281;
        System.out.println(meters +" meters is " + feet + " feet.");
    }

    public static void quitProgram()
    {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        System.out.println(0);
    }
    public static void showMenu()
    {
        System.out.println(" 1. Convert to kilometers ");
        System.out.println(" 2. Convert to inches ");
        System.out.println(" 3. Convert to feet ");
        System.out.println(" 4. Quit the program ");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

        double meters;
        int choice;



        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a distance in meters: ");
        meters = keyboard.nextDouble();
        while (meters <=0 || meters > 0)
        {
            if (meters > 0)
            {
                showMenu();
                meters = keyboard.nextDouble();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than 1");
                meters = keyboard.nextDouble();
                showMenu();
            }
        }

        choice = keyboard.nextInt();
        switch(choice) //note the use of switch case
            {
            case 1: showKilometers(meters);
            break;
            case 2:showInches(meters);
            break;
            case 3:showFeet(meters);
            break;
            case 4:
            quitProgram();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's an infinite loop. You might as well write `while (true)`

Try either `while (meters <= 0)` or `while (meters >0)`

Or:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a distance in meters: ");
meters = keyboard.nextDouble();
while (meters < 1 || meters.isNaN())
{
    System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than 1");
    meters = keyboard.nextDouble();
    showMenu();
}
```

Your output also specifies "Greater than 1", so your condition needs to agree.

Comment: Unless the user is mean enough to enter a NaN ;)

Comment: He might aswell remove the if too.

Comment: When the program runs and the `while` loop is false it doesn't run the rest of the program.

Comment: @IvanNewYork _it doesn't run the rest of the program_ isn't that the point of using the `while` loop?

Comment: @John To add an error message, do you think I should do an IF statement since the while loop will not run when false?

Comment: @IvanNewYork Not sure exactly what you have in mind, but I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 while (meters <=0 || meters > 0) is an infinite loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition specified in the loop is contradictory. The condition must be used like this :

```
while (meters >= 0)
{
    // logical statements here if the condition is satisfied
}
else
{
    // logical statements here if the condition is not satisfied
}
```